# Turning off security for /

Tags: asp.net, openid, authorization

I am using openID on my site for login and need it to fetch the XRDS document
So I unsecured it

```
<location path="xrds.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

But when the openID server checks the domain for the location of this file it asks for http://example.com/ and it should receive a header telling it where this file is. It can’t get this because the page redirects to a login page and the openID server doesn’t follow the redirect.  The solution is to unsecure / . I tried  and can go to domain/default.htm no problem as it is not secured but if I go to just / it’s still secured.

If there a way to specify a location for / ?
Note:  path attribute must be a relative virtual path.  It cannot contain any of '?' ':' '\' '*' '"' '<' '>' or '|'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root path is represented by the core Web.config file that is NOT wrapped in a `&lt;location/&gt;` tag. You would need to remove security on the whole application, then selectively apply it to the files and child folders you want security to be enabled on. I know its not really a pretty answer, but sadly, thats the way it works.

Comment: Ya this is what I did, Sadly it's hard to maintain as new folders are added and old ones are removed.

Comment: @Jeff: I totally agree, its kind of a morbid oversight on Microsoft's behalf. I've had this problem myself many times in the past, and I've always hated dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "~" as the path yet?  It points at the application root, which (depending on your particular configuration) likely is the same folder as "/" for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

How about the empty string for a path?